# Set a Resource's Storyboard TargetProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a storyboard defined on my common module:

```
<Storyboard 
    x:Key="stbMessage"
    >
    <Storyboard.TargetProperty>Opacity</Storyboard.TargetProperty>
    <Storyboard.Duration>0:0:4</Storyboard.Duration>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
        <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:2.7" />
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:3" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Now I want, in all my modules, to reference this storyboard and set *TargetProperty* according to the required situation.

```
<!-- some event occured, starting storyboard -->
<interactions:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Stb_controlvalue}" Storyboard.TargetName="controlvaluetext"  />
```

However, an error occurs that no destination is specified from DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames.

If, instead I set TargetName on Storyboard definition, it works.

What's the matter?

Comment: You set the Storyboard.TargetName property of the ControlStoryboardAction. This doesn't apply to the Storyboard. You cannot change the definition of a resource from the place you reference the resource.